# How to join client ubuntu 14.04 to Domain windows

Tags: 14.04, domain-server, join

I download and  follow the instructions http://download1.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/?Pass=True

But..
I join domain success, then reboot client, login domain user error.
( I'm sure the account and the correct password )

Can anyone help?
Tks !

Comment: Can you explain how did you installed a software designed for kernels 2.4/2.6 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I install Linux 2.4/2.6 kernel 64-bit DEB.

Comment: Can you help me ?

Comment: Sorry, not really my area of expertise. I don't use Windows at all and certainly not for servers.

Answer (score 0):

don't waste your time with PBIS...following are the steps  for joining 14.04 with domain server.

my Active Directory domain is : abc.com
server name : server.abc.com
user Name (admin) : satish

1. download : centrify-suite-2017.1-deb7-x86_64.tgz for Ubuntu 14.04 (for Ubuntu 14.04 64bit)
   1(a) type su and give password. you will get root login.
2. right click on file and select extract here
3. change directory what ever you have like : cd /Downloads/Centify/centrify
4. Install samba services : sudo apt-get install samba
5. type ls, you should see install-express.sh
6. type ./install-express.sh
7. Just press enter ...enter ....n enter....
   (i) provide Active Directory domain name when it ask "Please enter the   Active Directory domain to check [company.com]:abc.com (for my case) 
   (ii) Enter the Active Directory authorized user [administrator]: satish (type here administrator, in my case satish is administrator
      than enter password
   (iii) Enter the name of the domain controller [auto detect]: server.abc.com (ds is my server name..you must type your server name)
   Next enter ...enter ...enter...till restart automatic.

thats it....you are joined with your windows domain server...ask for any query....n....remember don't forget to uninstall bloody pbis from your computer if you preinstall the same and must network ip configure according to your netowrk